# IE8 and JQuery's trim()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, trim

I am making use of trim() like so:

```
if($('#group_field').val().trim()!=''){
```

Where `group_field` is an input element of type text. This works in Firefox but when I try it on IE8 it gives me this error:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

When I remove the trim(), it works fine on IE8. I thought the way I am using trim() is correct?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if($.trim($('#group_field').val()) != ''){
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Thanks, I thought JQuery's functions were chain-able and that's how they all worked!

Comment: @Abs: `val()` does not return a jQuery object, so chaining is out of the option. You were calling the `trim()` method on a string, but IE does not know about `String.trim`.

Comment: FWIW, I just failed someone's Code Review because they used the OP's syntax. They obviously didn't test in any version of MSIE.

Comment: On a side note, if you're testing MSIE8, it doesn't know about Array.indexOf(). Use jQuery.inArray() instead.

Answer (score 14):

You should use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), like this:

```
if($.trim($('#group_field').val()) !='') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, Javascript String does not have the method trim. 
If you want to use function trim, then use

```
<script>
    $.trim(string);
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Another option will be to define the method directly on `String` in case it's missing:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    //Your implementation here. Might be worth looking at perf comparison at
    //http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript
    //
    //The most common one is perhaps this:
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Then `trim` will work regardless of the browser:

```
var result = "   trim me  ".trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

To globally trim input with type text using jQuery:

```
/**
 * Trim the site input[type=text] fields globally by removing any whitespace from the
 * beginning and end of a string on input .blur()
 */
$('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
});
```