# Store the string returned by an ASP.NET helper into a javascript var: SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What I want to do is store the string returned by this ASP.NET helper into a javascript var.

My code:

```
    function doSomething(id){
     var htmlString = '@Html.TextArea("test", new { @rows = "1" })';
    }
```

The generated javascript along with the error in chrome:

```
 var htmlString = '<textarea cols="20" id="test" name="test" rows="1">
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
 </textarea>';
```

Comment: Did you want Textarea box value in javascript.

Comment: I want the html string the helper generates as follows: <textarea cols="20" id="test" name="test" rows="1"></textarea>  .... is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting error, because `Html.TextArea` return `textarea` with new line. It is not just chrome problem, put this in firebug console:

```
var htmlString = '<textarea cols="20" id="test" name="test" rows="1">
</textarea>';
```

And you will get:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

More details: [ASP.NET MVC Textarea HTML helper adding lines when using AntiXssLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472705/asp-net-mvc-textarea-html-helper-adding-lines-when-using-antixsslibrary)