# IE8 issue with jQuery attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8 and am receiving an error of “object not found” with the line:

```
var l_classList = $(this).attr('class').trim().split(/\s+/);
```

The actual code block is as follows:

```
$( "div.panel" ).each(function(index) {
    var l_classList = $(this).attr('class').trim().split(/\s+/);
    if ( l_classList.length == 1 ) $(this).addClass("panel-default");
});
```

Any ideas of how to get around this within IE8?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).prop("className")`? (Or just `this.className`?)

Comment: Tried both your suggestions and unfortunately no luck.

Comment: What line of code is giving you that error? (Also, is it really "object not found"?  That's a weird error.) Their might be no `.trim()` function on the String prototype in IE8.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Looks like you are adding the class `panel-default` to each div element that has only one class set, and since you used `.panel` as selector already, that class could only be `panel` in any case? Just checking if the class _is_ `panel` (after trimming the value, should your environment make that necessary) seems a little more direct than the hoops you’re jumping through …

Comment: try: `$.trim($(this).attr('class')).split(/\s+/);` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3439327/2387772))

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support the trim() method.

Try adding this to your helper functions and then run your script.

```js
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    (function() {
        var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
        String.prototype.trim = function() {
            return this.replace(rtrim, '');
        };
    })();
}
```

Comment: @Cracker0dks just added a comment about that to OP, you beat me to it by about 4 seconds =]

Comment: @yuvi yeahh Im a winner :D